# ueye undefined reference using catkin_make

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, ueye

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I stumbled upon a difficulty, when trying to work with uEye camera. I've added
include "ueye.h"

to work with code:

```
HIDS hCam = 1;

INT nRet = is_InitCamera (&hCam, NULL);
```

Yet this is the output when I try to do catkin_make using my CMakeLists (http://pastebin.com/u8f4t2Fc)

```
CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/src/ros_aruco.cpp.o: In function `main':
ros_aruco.cpp:(.text+0x578): undefined reference to `is_InitCamera'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I add to make it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170241/ueye-undefined-reference-using-catkin_make/) by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-28**:
Ding dong! Correct answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add ${UEYE_LIBRARY} to the target_link_libraries for ros_aruco?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1